# Bootstrap 3 set options for individual modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the next piece of code trying to setup these properties for my bootstrap modal but when I place it into the `$(document).ready` the modal shows up when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModalBug').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
  });
});
```

How can I make to set these properties without the dialog show up on load page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set show to false. It defaults to true see the options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModalBug').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false,
      show: false
  });
});
```

Comment: which one is the value for enable backdrop to true? @Jared

Comment: It is the backdrop option and it looks like you have it set. Alternatively you could use true @martinezjc

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModalBug').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false,
      show:false
  });
});
```

You can also use data attributes like `data-backdrop="static"`.

This way you don't need to write any of your script for modal unless you need explicitly for callbacks.